# Why is CMake ending prematurely in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator, nmake, cmake-server

I'm new to Qt Creator and wanted to import an existing CMake project into it. I loaded the CMakeLists.txt file as a project, and after running CMake, it found my files like I hoped.

But when it builds, it seems to end prematurely after one second. Here is the log:

```
17:11:46: Running steps for project My-GUI...
17:11:46: Starting: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --target clean
17:11:46: Starting: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --target spectrumSaver
    "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\Excellims\My-GUI -BC:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\Excellims\build-My-GUI-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Default --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 /nologo -L                  spectrumSaver
    "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\Excellims\My-GUI -BC:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\Excellims\build-My-GUI-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Default --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
    "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\Excellims\build-My-GUI-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Default\CMakeFiles 7
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\spectrumSaver.dir\all
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f shared\CMakeFiles\shared.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  shared\CMakeFiles\shared.dir\depend
    "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "NMake Makefiles" C:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\Excellims\My-GUI C:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\My-GUI\src\shared C:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\My-GUI\build-My-GUI-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Default C:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\My-GUI\build-My-GUI-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Default\shared C:\Users\user\WorkingFiles\Excellims\build-My-GUI-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Default\shared\CMakeFiles\shared.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f shared\CMakeFiles\shared.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  shared\CMakeFiles\shared.dir\build
[ 28%] Built target shared
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\spectrumSaver.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\spectrumSaver.dir\depend
17:11:47: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

You can see that CMake reports the build is 28% complete, just before ending.

I can't find any information on this and all my fiddling has yet to fix it. I'm using CMake 3.7.2 (that comes with CLion), but I have also used CMake 3.8.2 (independently installed). This is on Windows 7, with Qt Creator 4.3.0 using the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what was causing it to stop building prematurely, but after I restarted Qt Creator, the problem went away. It now builds completely.